# ModSecurity WAF RESPONSE_BODY note working

Tags: security, mod-security2

Im new to Web Application Firewalls and im trying to get modsecurity to work.

Im testing out some config this is what i got so far.

```
SecResponseBodyAccess On
SecResponseBodyMimeType text/plain text/html
SecResponseBodyLimit 524288
SecResponseBodyLimitAction ProcessPartial
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "<script>" "phase:4,log,deny,id:101"
SecRule ARGS|ARGS_NAMES|REQUEST_COOKIES|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|REQUEST_HEADERS|REQUEST_HEADERS_NAMES "<script>" "phase:2,log,deny,id:101"
```

I just cant get the response body with a script tag to be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you turned ModSecurity on with the following config?:

```
SecRuleEngine On
```

You can also turn on debugging which will show you more info as each rule is processed:

```
SecDebugLog /path/to/modsec-debug.log
SecDebugLogLevel 9
```

Comment: This helped me to troubleshoot the real problem. I had to add `SecDisableBackendCompression On`

Answer (score 0):

You have rules with the same ID, that shouldn't work.